# How does zfs know which snapshots to send with the `-I` flag?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

From the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5461/gbchx.html):

> A group of incremental snapshots can be combined into one snapshot by
> using the zfs send -I option. For example:
>
> ```
> # zfs send -I pool/fs@snapA pool/fs@snapD > /snaps/fs@all-I
> ```

How does zfs know that `@snapB` and `@snapC` are in between `@snapA` and `@snapD`? Is there are parent/child relationship between snapshots? If yes, how can I query the parent of a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are dataset children.

Snapshots are like pointers on a timeline.

Try `zfs list -rt snap -o name,creation` to get the snapshot chronology,

Comment: I this really how zfs implements this? The creation time is not reliable as it depends on the system time, ntp, etc.

Comment: My comment was just a spot, not an implementation explanation. Your comment is correct: it could be interesting to test how ZFS works under datetime changes… I think if you had trouble related to datetime on your server, you'll get problem before ZFS management (-:

Comment: I use zfs also on laptops and don’t want a dead motherboard battery mess up by snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it : ZFS use *Transaction Groups* and datasets (as snapshot are) have a native property : `createtxg`.

> `createtxg`: The  transaction group (txg) in which the dataset was created. Bookmarks have the same createtxg as the snapshot they are initially tied to. This property is suitable for ordering a list of snapshots, e.g. for incremental send and receive.

See [ZFSPROPS(7) manpage](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zfsprops&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+15.0-CURRENT)